# Webpage with several IP-cameras' streams

Tags: flash, applet, ffmpeg, streaming, xuggler

I have some live RTSP streams from IP-cameras with H.264 video and g-729 sound codecs. I need to display them on a webpage, which could be opened in any popular browser in Windows, Linux and Mac. Also, there must be an option to record and to save to user's PC a video from any stream to flv file , using Start/Stop recording button.
The problem is, I don't know what technologies to choose: all solutions which I came up with, have several problems.

The first variant is to transcode stream to RTMP with FFmpeg, changing audio codec to MP3.That way it can be played with a small Flash app. It works, but I don't know, how to save video because the .flv-writing library requires Bitmaps and ByteArray sound data chunks as input. It's not a problem to get images from Video class, but I have no idea about sound: SoundMixer class couldn't recieve any data from Video (or NetStream) with it's computeSpectrum method. So , impossibility of writing sound to .flv is the only problem of this solution.

Another variant is to use java applet, based on Xuggler library. It work's fine, but the library is VERY huge, and "applet's" size is near 40mb!

I also tryed Silverlight (it's problem is, it isn't popular, so everyone have to download it for 1 app only) and HTML5 (which does not allow capturing sound from incoming live stream, like Flash), but they give no solutions too. So I don't know, how to realize this project, can you give me any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using Wowza as a proxy? It has lots of add-ons and built-in features that would allow things like you mention. You could pull those camera streams, record the stream to the file in parallel and push it in your webpages using any player you want.

The idea is that once your stream is in Wowza, you can do anything about it.

http://www.wowza.com/

It also has a nice forum with support team online to answer your questions.

Comment: I'm using Wowza already and I know how to record streams with it (due to powerful developer's tools it's quite easy). You mean I have to send commands to mediaserver, when I press "Start/Stop record" button, and then download a complete flv file with URLLoader in Flash? It'll work, but the problem is that in this variant user have double traffic to download: first, watching livestream, second, downloading flv? I'm right?

Comment: I think download of result file is the only way to do it unless you decide to have some "thick client" like xuggler.